# Deselect all the series legends in Apache Echarts

Tags: javascript, echarts, apache-echarts

we can manually deselect specific series in Echarts using

```
legend:{
selected: { 'Series1': false, 'Series2': false }
}
```

However, I have more than 200 series in Echart, so is there any way I can deselect all dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Use the API method [`unselect`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#action.unselect):

```js
chartInstance.dispatchAction({ type: 'unselect', seriesIndex: 0 })
```